# How do I update Kivy elements from a thread?

Tags: python, kivy, python-multithreading

I have a socket client that calls a `View()` class every time it receives a message. I've split my code in such a way such that this class can simply use `print()` or any other display method, as I like. However, it seems that Kivy is not fond of this method. I've extended Kivy's `BoxLayout` class for my view and can call the `message()` function. The class looks something like this:

```
class View(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(View, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.btn = Button(text='Default')
        # Bind button press method
        self.btn.bind(on_press=self.message)
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
    def message(self, message):
        self.btn.text = 'Meow'
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Meow'))
        print(str(message))
```

The message function is indeed called and it prints but the interface does not update. When I press the button however, it does update the interface as well as print.

I've looked into using a `StringProperty` to modify the button text but have failed that too. Just as a note, in case what I'm doing is completely infeasible, I'm trying to later draw an entire interface consisting of `width * height` buttons, in the form of a board.

Any input is very much appreciated, it's been driving me insane.

---

**EDIT 1***
I've followed on a few comments and tried a few things out. I've added a `Clock` class and have it schedule an `update()` method from `View`. The update method simply changes the text of a few elements. I've noticed it works when I schedule it to, as shown below:

```
def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.btn.text = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(32))
def message(self, message):
    try:
        print(message)
        self.text = 'sending'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The thread now simply assigns the text property as seen in `message()`. The periodically triggered `update()` methods works too, assigning random text. Now the issue however that it cannot set the text. This does not work:

```
def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.btn.text = self.text
```

I must be doing wrong elsewhere, any suggestions?

---

**EDIT 2***
The error I'm trying to debug is [here](https://github.com/TimurKiyivinski/falampous-coconut-appreciator/blob/kivy/client.py).

Comment: you cannot modify UI elements or properties from a thread other than the mainthread.  Look at the Kivy ```Clock``` class for scheduling functions to run on the mainthread.

Comment: Further to @bj0's answer, you can use the `@mainthread` decorator to apply this method to a function automatically.

Comment: Hey, I've edited the post with further findings. I appreciate the help, and the suggestion of using `Clock()` but as mentioned above, it's still not fully functional.

Answer (score 14):

Since you don't post a full working example, I can only guess at what your doing.  It seems you have an event (incoming message) on a thread, and you want to display some text when this occurs.  You need to 'push' UI updates to the main thread, but you don't need to do *periodic* updates with `Clock`, you can just schedule one-time calls with `Clock.schedule_once`.

```
from functools import partial

def update(self, text, *a):
    self.btn.text = text

def message(self, message):
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.update, message), 0)
```

As inclement mentioned, you can do this 'push to main thread' automatically with the [`@mainthread`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.mainthread) decorator:

```
@mainthread
def update(self, text):
    self.btn.text = text

def message(self, message):
    update(message)
```

This way, whenever you call `update` it will be executed on the main thread.

Comment: My intent was to not post a full working example as this is part of an assignment and I'd hate to have my work plagiarized. I've made the repo on GitHub public now, available [here](https://github.com/TimurKiyivinski/falampous-coconut-appreciator). I have since removed the clock methods and gone back to using `@mainthread`. The file you're looking for is `client.py`.

Comment: Usually when you don't want (or can't) post the code you are working on, just create a minimal bare-bones app that has the issue you are trying to solve.  It helps when people can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ok, after glancing at your code, it doesn't look like a Kivy problem but a ```multiprocessing``` problem.  Separate processes don't share memory so a lot of your references between objects will not work right.  Use threading instead and it should work the way you are thinking