# Screen isn't updated in kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

So this is simple sudoku solver with backtracking (using recursion). It's made so after every recursion the screen updates (to show a change), but it doesn't display anything until it's completely done. Where's the problem? Also maybe there is better way to update screen after each change?

The code:

'''

```
def update_numbers(self):
    self.clear_widgets()
    
    greeting = Label(text="Sudoku", pos=(self.width/2 - 70, 1200), size_hint=(0.2, 0.08))
    self.add_widget(greeting)
    
    v_x, v_y = 15, 955
    for k, row in enumerate(board, start=1):
        for k1, col in enumerate(row, start=1):
            self.add_widget(Label(text=str(col), pos=(v_x, v_y), size_hint=(0.3, 0.3)))
            v_x += 60
        
        v_x = 15
        v_y -= 60
    
def solve(self, bo):
    self.update_numbers() # should update the screen

    #everything further is solver itself

    find = find_empty(bo)
    if find:
        row, col = find
    else:
        return True
    
    for i in range(1, 10):
        if valid(bo, (row, col), i):
            bo[row][col] = i
            
            if self.solve(bo):
                return True
            
            bo[row][col] = 0

    return False
```

'''

Edit:
After looking at similar problem here: [How do I update Kivy elements from a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809219/how-do-i-update-kivy-elements-from-a-thread)

I found a solution to this problem:
'''

```
def display_setup(self):
    greeting = Label(text="Sudoku", pos=(self.width/2 - 70, 1200), size_hint=(0.2, 0.08))
    self.add_widget(greeting)
    
    v_x, v_y = 15, 955
    for k, row in enumerate(board, start=1):
        for k1, col in enumerate(row, start=1):
            the_label = Label(text=str(col), pos=(v_x, v_y), size_hint=(0.3, 0.3))
            self.labels.append(the_label)
            self.add_widget(the_label)
            
            v_x += 60
            
        
        v_x = 15
        v_y -= 60

@mainthread
def update_numbers(self, *dt):
    for k, label in enumerate(self.labels):
        row = k // 9
        label.text = str(board[row][k % 9])
    
def solve(self, bo):
    Clock.schedule_once(self.update_numbers, 0)
    time.sleep(0.05)
            .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running `solve()` on the main thread (as it would be if it is triggered by a Button), then the display cannot be updated until the `solve()` method returns. The display can only be updated  on the main thread, and only when the main thread is available.

The fix is to start the `solve()` process in another thread (see [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/threading.html)), then mark the `update_numbers()` method as a `mainthread` method:

```
@mainthread
def update_numbers(self):
```

That causes the `update_numbers()` method to be run on the main thread.

Comment: Well i tried using @mainthread, but got an error which said "NameError: name 'mainthread' is not defined". So i used mainthread from kivy.clock , but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you run the `solve()` in a new thread?

Comment: I did, however after looking at similar problem i managed to fix the problem. Thank you for your help!